# Q format to IEEE Float to decimal converter tools

Tags: debugging

This is clone of [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/47470/q-format-to-ieee-float-to-decimal-converter-tools?noredirect=1#comment91659_47470) as it was off-topic in Signal processing SE, I am asking question in this SE.

I am looking for Q format (fixed point) converter tools, either in excel sheet or standalone applications. They will be helpful in development and debugging DSP applications in my work. I found [this](https://www.venea.net/web/qformatconverter) and it is not convenient to convert between decimal to Q format either way. If any one is aware of them let me know.

Comment: It might be helpful if you included more information. For example, what do you find inconvenient about the tool that you already discovered? What would make it more convenient? However, to be honest, this sounds like something very specialized. It might be simpler to write something yourself or commission someone to write something for you. (Maybe ask it as a puzzle on the [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) site? This is partly a joke, but partly not. I don't know if it would be welcome there.)

Comment: Also, even if the question is off-topic for the DSP site, maybe that site has forums on which you can ask more informally what other folks in the DSP community use.